# Regex to exclude one character only once and then should allow it

Tags: regex

Regex that I tried:

`[+1]?[^0-9]`,

`[+1{1}]?[^0-9]`,

`[^+1]?[^0-9]+` - this allows all `1`'s

Sample number :
`+1 (634) 841-4313`

target :
`6348414313`

it should remove characters:
`+1 () -`

my regex removes :
`+1 () 1-1`

Can any of you help me here with this?

Comment: do you use a programming language or you need all in a one-line regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^\+1\D*|\D`

This will remove "+1" at the start of the string, then any non-numeric character following it

Given "+1 (987) 6543-2101"
Returns "98765432101"

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about this as a couple of separate bits of regex. For example, `\+\d+\s` will identify a `+` followed by some number of digits, followed by a space. This will catch the `"+1 "`, and you can remove it.

Then just use `\(|\)` to identify either opening or closing braces. And then just find the hyphen with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `\+1?|[^0-9]`.

Thanks to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator `|`, the character `+` is matched before any other non-digit character and, in case, an optional `1` is removed.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/SYwe5c/1).

Beware that expressions like `[...]` (called [character sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) match every character specified in them. For instance, the one that you wrote `[+1{1}]` matches literally `+` or `1` or `{` or (redundantly) `1` or `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format is always `+number (number) number-number`, try this one:

```
\+[0-9]* ?\(([0-9]+)\) ?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)
```

Outputs three captured groups:

```
634
841
4313
```

Depending on your programming language, you should then concatenate those three found groups.

Test it online on [https://regex101.com/r/nB9ZQh/2](https://regex101.com/r/nB9ZQh/1).